# Insert entities into local storage table using Azure logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

We are trying to insert entities into a local storage table using Azure logic action. We are using Microsoft Azure storage emulator for storage. But we could not find built in action in azure logic apps to insert entities into table. As of now we could see below options ,

1. Delete table(preview)
2. Create table(preview)
3. List tables(preview)

Is there any option to insert entities into local storage table?

[image: Click here to view image]

Comment: have you tried the azure operations ?

Comment: is it for logic app standard ?

Answer (score 0):

***You will find insert entity as below:***

***Here i used `Consumption plan` while creating  logic app***

[image]

***or***

[image]